# Get li nodes but not li in child ul

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

I have a html structure that looks like this:

```
<ul class='plus'>
  <li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>
  <li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>
  <li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>
  <li>cxvcvxcv
      <ul>
         <li>ewfwefewfwef</li>
         <li>gergrjmkuykmuyk</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to grab the top level li items but not any in the child uls.

I currently grab all the li items with this code using HTMLAgilityPack:

```
nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class=\"plus\"]").SelectNodes(".//li");
```

How can I adapt this to exclude any lis contained in child uls?

Comment: Try changing `.//li` to `./li` or just `li`. If I recall correctly, `//` means to look at all descendants (and not just direct children)

Comment: I did have 'li' already and that didnt work, but I'll give './li' a try. Thanks.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: You can do this all in a single statement too, no need for the `SelectSingleNode` too.

Comment: Perhaps (from memory!) this: `document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul[@class=\"plus\"]/li")`?

Comment: Ok but that wouldn't directly address my issue with picking up child li's would it?

Comment: It should do it. If it had `//li` then that would pick up all descendants too.

Comment: @DavidG I just tried it and whilst it works inplace of my original code, it still picks up the child li's.

Comment: I've just tried it out on [here](http://xpath.online-toolz.com/tools/xpath-editor.php) and it works for me. Try it with `/li` and `//li` to see the difference.

Comment: I'm trying it on a live example and it isn't making any difference for me. Maybe there is something in the structure that I'm missing. I'll expand my code sample tomorrow.

Comment: `/li` and `//li` will give you the same results, as Phill Healey is seeing. I'm not sure how @DavidG is seeing it "work", but they will both give you all `<li>` nodes under the `<ul>` root, which inclues the one you don't want. Is iterating through this list and skipping over the child `<ul>` node not an option for you?

Comment: @JWiley Well I did it on the XPath tester website I linked, can you not see the difference in results between the 2?

Comment: They're different, yes, but he doesn't want the `<li>` node which is a child of `<ul>` returned at all, and `//li` will return him that. Technically, `/li` should be what he wants, but since he's still seeing the children of that `/li` node, it like he was wanting to avoid it altogether from his response to you.

Comment: @JWiley Like I said, the version that ends with the single forward slash doesn't

Comment: @DavidG I'm in agreement with you that `/li` instead of `//li` should be what he uses, don't get me wrong. It just seems like from his response he doesn't want the entire node.

Comment: @JWiley You are probably right there, I think he needs to understand what it's doing.

Comment: @DavidG perhaps you could enlighten me? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
//ul[@class="plus"]/li[not(child::*[local-name() = 'ul'])]
```

But this will of course *not* return the `li` node with `ul` as a child which I think you want included in your results:

```
<li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>

<li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>

<li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>

<li>cxvcvxcv
  </li>
```

You won't be able to "filter" the results to what you want as nodes, but you could use `text()` to get them that way:

```
//ul[@class="plus"]/li/text()
```

**Result:**

```
cxvcvxcv

cxvcvxcv

cxvcvxcv

cxvcvxcv



cxvcvxcv
```

You would see these as text nodes, and you could still iterate over them, but you will have to account for the empty nodes it places in for those nodes with children nodes.

**Edit:**
Your additional info makes the solution much simpler...

```
//ul[@class="plus"]/li/@href
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. I'll give it a try first thing in the morning and get back to you. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, i don't think this will work since the content of the Li's is a tags and I need to be able to grab the href attributes. I didn't realise it would be so complex to do and so kept the example HTML simple in my question.

Comment: Do you just want the href attributes? Or the text contents including those attributes?

Comment: @PhillHealey that makes it very simple, see the edit. What @DavidG was saying earlier with the change from `\\` to `\` is all you needed.

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try in the morning.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've had to put this on hold for a while. Hopefully I'll pick it up again next we and get back with an update. Thanks for your time and help.